# Javascript - Alterar valor de retorno usando o setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boas pessoal,

Precisava de alterar o valor de retorno ao clicar no botão, ou seja, primeiramente o `click` teria que retornar `false` e passados `x segundos` teria que retornar `true` e prosessguir com o evento.

O código é o seguinte:

```
$(".btnnext").on("click",function (e) {

if (newText != "" || newText2 != "" || newText3 != "" || newText4 != "") {

                
    var teste = false;
    

    setTimeout((function () {
        teste = true;
        console.log(teste);

        $(".btnnext").trigger("click");
        return teste;
    }), 2000);

    return teste;
   
}});
```

A minha abordagem passava por primeiro retornar falso e posteriormente com a função `setTimeout` alterar o valor de retorno e simular o clique de novo no botão.
Problema: O valor de retorno é alterado mas o evento não avança, o segundo clique não funciona.

[image: FOTO]

O que pretendo é que ao clicar no botão, por exemplo, quando passa do passo 2 para o 3, demore um x segundos

Comment: A questão é que lógica você está a tentar atingir com isto ? Porque certamente terá formas mais simples e direta para tal

Comment: @Isac acredito que haja uma forma mais simples, esta foi só a minha abordagem se houver uma mais fácil/direta melhor. O objetivo principal é ao clicar no botão parar o evento provocado por ele (ficar no mesmo DOM x segundos) e depois avançar.

Comment: Explique por palavras e coisas visuais o que você quer quer aconteça, e não como está a tentar resolver o problema. Quer clicar num botão e que ele permaneça uns segundos na página e depois seja removido é isso ?

Comment: O melhor é mesmo usar ajax para fazer o pedido ao backend e apenas quando obtiver a resposta do ajax atualiza a página e/ou navega para outro local. Assim faz tudo como é suposto e sem gambiarra.

Comment: @Isac o problema aqui prende-se com a alteração do DOM por parte do botão, o clique no botão é que despoleta as contas e como o domínio altera as contas não saem corretas. Eu preciso mesmo é de ao clicar no botão, "atrasar" um pouco a sua ação.

Comment: Como estás a despoletar no backend o inicio de fazer as contas? Podes adicionar essa informação a resposta? A mim parece-me que a sugestão do @Isac é a ideal, ao clicar no botão, fazer pedido AJAX e quando recebes o resultado do servidor, redireccionas o utilizador para a página seguinte.

Comment: Eu enganei-me, ou seja, com `backend ` queria dizer o clique do botão que está representado no código. Eu só não o pus porque é um pouco extenso... Sendo assim o mesmo clique despoleta as contas e a alteração do `DOM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei por resolver o problema da seguinte forma (um pouco trivial e, talvez, um bocado estranha):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Primeiro paro a propagação do evento proveniente do clique no link.

Depois faço o um novo clique no mesmo link passados x segundos:

```
setTimeout(function () { $('.next #btnnext').unbind().trigger('click') }, 200);
```

O meu maior erro foi estar a clicar num botão com uma classe definida e não um id. No meu caso a adição da classe `disable` não funcionava.

Answer (score 3):

Alterei a resposta, veja se se encaixa em algo semelhante a sua necessidade.

```js
$('input').click(() => {
  
  $('input').attr('disabled','true');
  var cor = getRandomColor();
  var i = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    //Toda sua logica vai ser feita aqui! 
    if(!$('#div'+i)[0]){
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('input').removeAttr('disabled');
      return;
    };
    $('#div'+i).css('background',cor);
    i++;
  },2000);
  
});

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: red;
}

input{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<input type="button" value="Start">
```

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela resposta. Esta solução tem um problema, o clique no botão não me para a alteração do DOM (ou página). Eu já tinha testado por o botão disable ou até a função `preventDefault()`, mas nada funciona

Comment: @AdrianoMaia, posso alterar a resposta pra sua necessidade, você quer parar a alteração no dom ? o que exatamente quer que aconteça quando o usuário clicar nele, tente falar da forma bem básica pra que eu possa te ajudar

Comment: Eu editei a minha pergunta veja se ajuda

Comment: Mas basicamente eu quero que quando ele passa do passo 2 para o 3 (com o clique do botão que está representado no código) ele demore x segundos, porque, quando ele passa de etapa alguns campos são escondidos, o que leva a que o DOM se altere e as contas saiam trocadas.

Comment: Ok, vou alterar a resposta!

Comment: @AdrianoMaia veja a alteração que fiz!

Comment: não funciona porque o ao clicar no botão ele avança na mesma para a próxima etapa... ele ignora o atributo disable